# Rails where clause that need to find records through another table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I have 4 tables

- brands
- boats
- motors
- boat_motor_packages

a brand has_many motors

a motor belongs_to a brand

a boat_motor_package belongs_to a boat and a motor

a boat has_many boat_motor_packages

I need to do 2 things

1. list the brand for each boat_motor_package
2. list the boat_motor_packages associated with each brand

For example,

I have 1 boat

I have 2 brands - "evinrude" and "mercury"

I have 4 motors, 2 under each brand

Here is how I want it to look in my view template

evinrude

- 50HP
- 60hp

mercury

- 55hp
- 65hp

Here is my controller action

```
def show
  @boat = Boat.find(params[:id])
  packages = BoatMotorPackage.where(boat: @boat).all

  @package_motor_brands = packages.map { |p| p.motor.brand }
end
```

@package_motor_brands is giving me all the brands I need

now I need to get to the motor packages that are associated with the boat and the motor.brand

I was trying to do somthing like this:

```
-@boat.motor_packages(brand).each do |motor_package|
```

and create a method in the Boat class that looked like this:

```
def motor_packages(brand)
  BoatMotorPackage.where(["boat => ? and motor.brand => ?", self, brand])
end
```

but this doesn't work. I get an error saying the motor.brand column doesn't exist. Which is true, because it's actualluy on the motor table. Does anyone know the right way to do this?

Here is my view incase that helps

```
- @package_motor_brands.each do |brand|
                              .col-xs-6.motor-group-container
                                %h5= brand.name
                                -@boat.motor_packages(brand).each do |motor_package|
                                .row
                                  .col-xs-12.motor-group
                                    %label.motor-group-name 
                                      %input#motorPackageRadios1{:name => "motorPackages", :type => "radio", :value => "#{motor_package.id}"}/
                                      ="#{motor_package.motor.hp.to_s}HP #{motor_package.motor.motor_type}"
                                    .motor-group-price="#{motor_package.price_in_cents}"
```

Answer (score -1):

If you're following Rails conventions, then the table that holds your `Motor` records would be called `motors` (plural), not `motor` (singular).